# Use ST_AsBinary from PostGIS in PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, well-known-binary

I'm trying to read the `St_AsBinary` from PostGIS and to have a `QgsGeometry`.

I could have it working with this code:

```
import binascii

postgis_connection = "qgistest"

metadata = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres')
connection = metadata.findConnection(postgis_connection)

sql = "SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)'));"

results = connection.executeSql(sql)
wkb = results[0][0]
    
# output from pgadmin4 SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)')
#   010100000000000000000014400000000000002440
# print(wkb)
# \x010100000000000000000014400000000000002440

# Remove \x at the beginning of the string to match PgAdmin4 output AND to make the QgsGeometry valid
wkb = wkb[2:]

geom = QgsGeometry()
geom.fromWkb(binascii.unhexlify(wkb))
assert geom.asPoint().x() == 5
assert geom.asPoint().y() == 10
```

I'm wondering if it's normal that I need to remove the first two characters in my string.

I have read about hexadecimals strings starting by `\x` but it does not seem to be related, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707954/how-to-remove-x-from-a-hex-string-in-python

Is there a cleaner way to remove these two characters or to read them?

Edit :

I tried from psql :

```
qgistest=# SELECT ST_AsEWKB(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)')) AS geom;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------------------------------
geom | \x010100000000000000000014400000000000002440

qgistest=# SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)') AS geom;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------
geom | 010100000000000000000014400000000000002440

qgistest=# SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)')) AS geom;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------------------------------
geom | \x010100000000000000000014400000000000002440
```

Comment: See here, the 2 first characters are ignored too : https://github.com/elpaso/quickwkt/blob/master/QuickWKT.py#L171

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. So it seems it's just a fact. Especially after my commands in psql above.

Comment: See here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html : `The entire string is preceded by the sequence \x (to distinguish it from the escape format).`

Comment: Ah great, I got the explanation.