# Calling ST_IsValid on a QgsGeometry in PyQGIS, referencing PyQGIS object in SQL statement

Tags: qgis-3, postgresql, pyqgis-3

I'd like to be able to verify the validity of a geometry of type QgsGeometry within PyQGIS.

From what I can understand, the steps are

1. Convert QgsGeometry to something that ST_IsValid will recognize.
2. Create connection to PostGIS database and import associated libraries.
3. Create SQL statement
4. Call SQL statement.

Ive referenced the following answer to create my solution, (which is almost the inverse of this answer - [Use ST_AsBinary from PostGIS in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411545/use-st-asbinary-from-postgis-in-pyqgis))

so far I have the following

```
import psycopg2
from PyQt5.QtSql import *

pg_geom = a_rec.geometry().asWkb()

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='db_name', host='localhost',port=5432, user='postgres',password='postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_GEOMFROMWKB(pg_geom));"

cur.execute(sql)
```

Unfortunately this is returning an error

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "pg_geom" does not exist

In the link above, the OP uses the following format

```
 sql = "SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)'));"
```

So the difference is I'm referencing a PyQGIS object in the SQL.

How do I pass the pg_geom object into the SQL statement?

Comment: I haven't tested this *at all*, but I would try something like: `pg_geom = a_rec.geometry().asWkt()` then: `sql = f"SELECT ST_IsValid(GeomFromText('{pg_geom}'));"` **But...** is there a particular reason you can't/don't want to stick with pure pyqgis and just do: `a_rec.geometry().isGeosValid()` to check the validity?

Comment: @Ben W - I actually do run this check, but geometry is returned as valid. The process works when inserting into gpkg's, but when inserting into postgis, I get an error saying polygon needs at least 4 points in each ring - have made the assumption that GEOS is returning valid, but is not valid geometry for postgis, so am wanting to verify it before database transaction. Not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: PostGIS is built on top of GEOS and the actual geometric validity check is the same. The issue is your formatting; your SQL string literal is *literally* inserting the *string* `'pg_geom'`, not the value of the variable!

Comment: @geozelt - The GEOS check is done on QgsGeometry. However I insert into postgis using pyqgis 'with edit' statement. its during that transaction that the geometry comes back as erroneous. (ERROR: Polygon must have at least four points in each ring.) If what you are saying is true, that means somewhere in the back end of pyqgis, the conversion into wkb for the postgis transaction, is creating invalid geometry. There might be solution somewhere here though - ill try to convert into wkb from QgsGeometry manually, then check using GEOS.